# Can't connect azure sql db as connection manager in CDC control task in VS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, cdc

**ERROR :**

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.databases' is
> not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Trying to put azure sql db(s3 and s0) as destination in CDC control task and source is VM.

Comment: Possible root causes of the issue is in Azure SQL Database, we are not able to do the query into master database(master.sys.databases table in this case), we will need to use external datasource to do so, however, the query getting data from master.sys.database in the SSIS CDC control task component looks like hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

Please try connect directly to a database (`Initial Catalog=yourdbname`)